# Eager load related entity without explicit foreign key in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working on a project involving a legacy database schema and I'm running into problems when trying to load a related entity with Entity Framework (v6). Here is a simplified example of the data model that is being used:

```
public partial class Product {
    public virtual Delivery Delivery { get; set; }
    public virtual string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual int? VersionNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string SocialNumber { get; set; }
}

public partial class Delivery {
    public virtual string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual int? VersionNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string SocialNumber { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to include the related `Delivery` when retrieving a list of `Product`s with a given `SocialNumber`. A `Delivery` is related to a `Product` when the following condition is satisfied: `product.OrderNumber == delivery.OrderNumber && product.VersionNumber == delivery.OrderNumber && product.SocialNumber == delivery.SocialNumber`.

The easiest way to do this would be calling `Include`. However, that seems impossible since EF states that `product.Delivery` is not a valid navigation property. I've tried to get the wanted result by using a projection, but failed. I'd be thankful if anyone could explain the best EF/LINQ approach to get a list of `Product`s (+ their related `Delivery`) with a given `SocialNumber`.

---

**Update**: I think I should elaborate some more.

---

The main issue is that I'm dealing with a legacy database that does not have explicit (composite) keys on every table. For example, the `Delivery` and `Product` classes are mapped to tables that don't have a primary key. Since EF needs a primary key, dummy keys are defined as follows:

```
dbModelBuilder.Entity<Product>().hasKey(pk => new { pk.OrderNumber });
```

The entity classes are generated by a code generator, so adding annotations there isn't the solution I'm looking for. I guess it should be possible to define these things via the DbModelBuilder, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

---

**Update**: Figured out a solution.

---

The following query functions as expected (only showing the LINQ-query that should provide pairs of Product and related Delivery):

```
from data in _dartz3Context.V_VOV_GBA_DATAs
join delivery in _dartz3Context.VOV_GBA_AANLEVERINGs
    on new { Bsn = data.MunicipalBasicAdministrationSocialSecurityNumber, Version = data.VersionNumber, PolicyNumber = data.InsurancePolicyNumber } 
    equals new { Bsn = delivery.MunicipalBasicAdministrationSocialSecurityNumber, Version = delivery.VersionNumber, PolicyNumber = delivery.InsurancePolicyNumber }
where data.MunicipalBasicAdministrationSocialSecurityNumber == socialSecurityNumber
select new { Data = data, Delivery = delivery }
```

Comment: Add navigation properties in your EF model. The lack of a proper foreign key doesn't prevent you from creating navigation properties in your model.

Comment: Isn't ``Product.Delivery`` already a navigation property?

Comment: Because of the lack of foreign keys you probably need to specify what key(s) make up the relationship. Given that it's a multi-part key I'm not sure this will work but try adding three `[ForeignKey]` attributes to the `Delivery` property identifying the `OrderNumber`, `VersionNumber`, and `SocialNumber` as the foreign keys.

Comment: maybe you should consider using a composite foreign key to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a composite key on your entities using annotations or the fluent api:

```
public partial class Product {
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public virtual string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public virtual int? VersionNumber { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public virtual string SocialNumber { get; set; }
}

public partial class Delivery {
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), ForeignKey("Product")]
    public virtual string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("Product")]
    public virtual int? VersionNumber { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2), ForeignKey("Product")]
    public virtual string SocialNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/813912/Create-Primary-Key-using-Entity-Framework-Code-Fir

Fluent API Version:

```
// Composite primary key 
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasKey(d => new { d.OrderNumber, d.VersionNumber, d.SocialNumber }); 

// Composite foreign key 
modelBuilder.Entity<Delivery>()  
    .HasRequired(c => c.Product)  
    .WithMany(d => d.Delivery) 
    .HasForeignKey(d => new { d.OrderNumber, d.VersionNumber, d.SocialNumber });
```

Comment: Using annotations is unfortunately not the solution I'm looking for. The entity classes are generated with a code generator and I'd rather not change stuff in those classes. I updated the OP with some more elaboration on the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The approach you described gave the correct result. Actually solved the problem with the LINQ query in the OP, but thanks!